# SaveAs to CSV in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: vba, macos, excel, csv

I'm experienced VBA developer but have no enough experience in Mac to complete my very simple project. I want to export sheets to CSV and save them into the same directory where workbook stored.

I already created a new workbook (ActiveWorkbook) with data copied from the main workbook and fully worked Windows part of code. But in Mac I cant make this part to work, no files created in result:

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & sheetname & ".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

I read few sources and found that Excel for Mac 2016 requires to call GetSaveAsFilename dialog with initial filename with manual confirmation to do it, so I modified my code like this:

```
#If Mac Then
    s_fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & sheetname & ".csv")                                          

    If s_fname <> False Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs s_fname, 6                                                     
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
#Else
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & sheetname & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False                                     
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
#End If
```

Macro creates files with data but they saved in XLSX not CSV:
[image: No CSV but XLSX created] and dialog have xlsx as default format: [image: SaveAs Filetype default]

When I'm trying to set FileFilter I have no files saved again (I assume Mac not supports this attribute). When I try to do replacement:

```
s_fname=replace(s_fname,".xslx",".csv")
```

I still have .xlsx files in the folder.

Can you suggest please which GetSaveAsFilename FileFilter value I must to set in the code to force CSV save instead of XLSX? Or anotehr VBA solution to do it (file format change, after-save renaming etc).

Thank you,
Viacheslav

Comment: Have a look at what Ron did: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac016.htm

Comment: I read that too. That code based on a loop where user must select proper format in the FileType dropdown. But I need to proceed is without any action from user side as possible

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to change first part as this one:

```
If Mac Then
    OutputFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "-") & ".csv"                                          

    If OutputFile <> False Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False                                                     
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
```

Comment: ActiveWorkbook have no name yet - it is result of Workbooks.Add. Also I tried similar approach: it wont work in 2016 without calling of Application.GetSaveAsFileanme

Comment: I follow this way: [link to ms](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/vba-macro-in-excel-2016-for-mac-saveas-will-not/86d6855f-241d-4b8d-b233-cccd7184c67b) but FileType still be xlsx as you see on the 2nd screenshot